# В чем смысл использования динамического выделения памяти для переменных?

Tags: c++

Объясните мне пожалуйста, есть ли смысл и какой он в использовании **динамических переменных**(именно переменных, не массивов) (кроме того что их просто можно потом удалить)? Я посмотрел много сайтов и везде пишут только про динамические массивы, я это понял, что если я изначально не знаю размер массива его лучше сделать динамическим и тд. я понял вот это:

```
int* a = new int[size];
```

но зачем и в каких случаях мне нужно вот это:

```
int* a = new int(number);
```

Есть ли в этом какой то еще смысл, кроме того что ее можно создавать/очищать когда нужно?

P.S 
я понимаю как и зачем нужны динамические массивы, мне нужно только объяснения про динамические переменные!

Comment: Обычно их используют в качестве аргументов, передаваемых в создаваемый thread или callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Объясните мне пожалуйста, есть ли смысл и какой он в использовании
>   динамических переменных (кроме того что их просто можно потом
>   удалить)?

Да, в этом есть глубокий смысл, так как удалив уже использованный массив, Вы можете на этом месте расположить другой массив и работать с ним. Кроме того, статические массивы занимают место в экзешнике (и экзешник становится больше), а динамические массивы не занимают место в экзешнике (и экзешник становится меньше).

> если я изначально не знаю размер массива его
>   лучше сделать динамическим

В этом тоже преимущество динамических массивов. Часто при компиляции неизвестно, сколько потребуется места для данных. Для статических массивов приходится резервировать место по-максимуму, что неудобно, хотя бы потому, что размер ОЗУ на разных машинах м.б. разным. Динамические массивы лишены этого недостатка.

Вобщем динамические массивы позволяют более гибко использовать ценный ресурс системы - ОЗУ.

UPD1:

> Объясните пожалуйста зачем на ДИНАМИЧЕСКИЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ, не массивы

Во-первых, динамическая переменная может быть размером поболее иного массива. Конкретно, класс может содержать большой массив (и не один) и тогда все сказанное относится и к единичному экземпляру переменной. Во-вторых, много одиночных переменных разных типов также могут динамически создаваться и уничтожаться во время работы программы, экономя ОЗУ в рантайме и экономя размер экзешника. Опять же Вам неизвестно при компиляции, по какой ветке пойдет выполнение программы. А в зависимости от ветки программа может вообще не будет создавать какие-то переменные. И таким образом программа съэкономит ОЗУ.

UPD2:

Однако учтите, что создание динамической переменной или массива в куче довольно затратная по времени операция (по сравнению с созданием стековой или статической переменной). Поэтому к этому вопросу надо подходить творчески и соблюдать баланс между экономией ОЗУ и быстродействием программы.

Comment: так мой вопрос был как раз про переменные а не про массивы!! я же сказал что понял как массивы использовать а вопрос конкретно про переменные

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста зачем на ДИНАМИЧЕСКИЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ, не массивы

Comment: @leocoolguy см. UPD1 в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* a = new int[size];
```

здесь создается массив на size элементов.

```
int* a = new int(number);
```

а здесь создается один int в куче, который инициализируется значением number. Обычно такое не нужно, но если объект чуть посложнее, то используется постоянно.